react native Beacons manager - expo
I'm new in react native and I have a problem.
When I import the library react-native-beacons-manager the terminal gives me 2 errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ARMA_RSSI_FILTER' of null, js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes.

I'm using expo and I did the npm for the installation of the library.
I didn't use ARMA_RSSI_FILTER in my code so I think it refers to new.module.android.js a file that is in the library.

Since you are using expo, this library might not be compatible with Expo Go. To run such libraries you will have to use expo dev client.Just follow below steps and you might be able to use that library in your expo project as well.

Make sure to have eas account and link with project by eas build:configure
npx expo install expo-dev-client
eas build --profile development --platform android /
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios --clear-cache
Install the generated build in your device
in project terminal run command npx expo start --dev-client
Enter the generated url in the enter url TextInput of your app


don't let me create the build. it gives me this error:
Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information. If I go to the logs I find this:
Build failed with an exception.

Where:

Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/android/build.gradle' line: 30

What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-beacons-manager'.
